# A giant screen that can never be off

Tags: combinatorics

Form a $2000 \times 2002$ screen with unit screens. Initially, there are more than $1999 \times 2001$ unit screens which are on. In any $2 \times 2$ screen, as soon as there are $3$ unit screens which are off, the 4th screen turns off automatically. Prove that the whole screen can never be totally off.

This probably is supposed to be solved with a bijection, but I can't find one.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the statement.  I don't see what prevents all the screens from turning off at once.

Comment: @saulspatz A screen will _only_ turn off if it is in a $2\times 2$ subsquare of screens, where the three other screens in that subsquare are off. Not all screens will meet that requirement, so not all screens will initially turn off.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks, that makes it clear.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @BrianTung http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/bijections.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $A$ be the set of screens which are initially on, but which eventually turn off. For every screen in $A$, there is a particular $2\times 2$ square of screens which "caused" it to turn off (because the other three screens were off). Let $B$ be the set of $2\times 2$ subsquares; what is the cardinality of $B$? Then, let $f:A\to B$ be the function which given a screen, returns the $2\times 2$ subsquare which caused it to turn off. If there are multiple choices for this subsquare, choose one arbitrarily to use for the output of $f$.

Show that $f$ must be injective. What does this let you conclude about $|A|$?

Comment: This might have been an even better hint if the "injective" comment were missing!  ;)